# Default method with tupled parameters for an F# class

Tags: class, f#, methods, abstract

Why does this F# class not compile(with VS2010):

```
type Base =
    abstract func : (int * int) -> int

    default this.func (x : int, y : int) : int =
        x + y
```

The default implementation of func causes this compilation error:

```
Error   9   This override takes a different number of arguments to the corresponding abstract member
```

If I change it be a member:

```
type Base =
    abstract func : (int * int) -> int

    member this.func (x : int, y : int) : int =
        x + y
```

Then it compiles (though I believe now the abstract func lacks an implementation), and the type of the 2nd func matches the 1st.

On a related note, why doesn't the compiler require the 2nd definition of Base to have an AbstractClass attribute?

Comment: You are asking: "why **doesn't** the compiler require the 2nd definition to have an AbstractClass attribute?" - When I test this, the compiler **does** require the attribute. What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: @wmeyer: you're right. Because the file where I tested the above code had an error further on, intellisense didn't highlight the lack of an AbstractClass attribute as an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get rid of the parentheses:

```
type Base =
    abstract func : int * int -> int

    default this.func (x : int, y : int) : int =
        x + y
```

You can even shorten it a bit:

```
default this.func(x, y) = x + y
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the first version to compile, you need to write:

```
type Base1 =
    abstract func : (int * int) -> int
    default this.func( (x : int, y : int) ) : int =
        x + y
```

I don't have a link to the specification, but F# doesn't generally compile members as methods that take tuples as arguments. It usually uses .NET/C# friendly method with multiple arguments. The `abstract` member enforces this representation, so the `default` member needs to do the same using a more explicit syntax.

You're correct in understanding the second type - the second declaration is an abstract class with unimplemented abstract method (and another method that happens to have the same name). For this, F# requires `AbstractClass` attribute (it doesn't require it for the above, because it is not abstract).

Comment: Thanks. Although your answer is technically correct (and more informative) I've selected Daniel's answer as he had spotted that I didn't require the parentheses). I tend to get confused switching between F#, C# and C++.